# How can I center text inside an anchor without a block-level parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of anchor tags made to look like several boxes with texts in the middle of it. What I want is to set all text inside them perfectly centered, on width and on height. I could accomplish the height part with `display: inline-flex; align-items: center;`, but I couldn't set the text horizontaly centered. This is the HTML to those anchors and  it's styles:

```
<a class="tt-button" style="background: #808080; width: 100%; height: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px; display: inline-flex; align-items: center;" href="#">Reconhecimento</a>
```

All I want is a `text-align: center` effect on them. Any help?

```html
<a class="tt-button" style="background: #808080; width: 100%; height: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px; display: inline-flex; align-items: center;" href="#">Reconhecimento</a>
<a class="tt-button" style="background: #808080; width: 100%; height: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px; display: inline-flex; align-items: center;" href="#">Neurociência</a>
<a class="tt-button" style="background: #808080; width: 100%; height: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px; display: inline-flex; align-items: center;" href="#">Envolvimento Emocional</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `justify-content: center;`, like this:

```css
.tt-button {
  background: #808080; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100px; 
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
  display: inline-flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="tt-button" href="#">Reconhecimento</a>
<a class="tt-button" href="#">Neurociência</a>
<a class="tt-button" href="#">Envolvimento Emocional</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

My dear friend, you need to add this piece of code to your style.

```
justify-content: center;
```

It's the final one

```
<a class="tt-button" style="background: #808080;width: 100%;height: 100px;margin-bottom: 10px;display: inline-flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;" href="#">Reconhecimento</a>
```